# Custom Class to extend functionality in C# dll

Tags: c#, dll

I have .dll files. I have unzipped them using dot peek.

I want to change a function to extend some functionality of an existing class in the dll package. Below is a sample of the code.

```
using IdeaBlade.Persistence;
using IdeaBlade.Persistence.Rdb;
using IdeaBlade.Rdb;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Test.SV.Processor
{
  public class Processor
{

.....

  private static void ProcessRecords()
  {
    EntityQuery entityQuery = new EntityQuery(typeof (vEntry));
    entityQuery.Top = BatchSize;
    entityQuery.AddClause(vDataRow.HasBeenProcessedEntityColumn, EntityQueryOp.EQ, (object) 0);
    entityQuery.AddClause(vEntryDataRow.IsRealEntityColumn, EntityQueryOp.EQ, (object) 1);
    entityQuery.AddOrderBy(vEntryDataRow.EntityColumn, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    EntityList<vEntry> entities = PersistenceManager.DefaultManager.GetEntities<vEntry>((IEntityQuery) entityQuery, new QueryStrategy(FetchStrategy.DataSourceOnly, MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges));
    try
    {
      foreach (vEntry vEntry in (Collection<vEntry>) entities)
      {
        string tag = vEntry.Tag;
        if (Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.CompareString(tag, "Test", false) != 0)
        {
            SProcessor.ProcessEntry(vEntry);
        }
        else
          QProcessor.ProcessEntry(vEntry);
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      IEnumerator<vOpcJournalEntry> enumerator;
      enumerator?.Dispose();
    }
    }

  ........

  }
}
```

I want add a another if statement so basically I want to change the ProcessRecords() method.
Also I want to add new method that are called if the newly added if statement is true.

Is it possible to add this funcitonality or will i have to write a completely new program?

Comment: Do you not own the original code that created this dll?

Comment: If you have source code you can modify source and recompile the dll.

Comment: i don't own original code as in i have bought this application but have not written the code myself.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you don't have the original source code.

I you have used a decompiler (such as ILSpy), then you have certainly a feature to decompile the entire library into a C# project.

Then you will be able to change the code and recompile the library, but with a lot of cautions:

- it will not work if the original library was signed
- it will require that you have the tools required to compile the program
- it will also require that you have enough knowledge to know how to compile a .net c# project.

So it's not impossible, but not easily feasible.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have the source code. I thought i could write a custom class in which i could override the existing method using the original class and dll files. Based on your answer I am assuming that is not possible.

I have to some how decompile the whole code and change the original class, and then compile it again.